# What age is appropriate for playing Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I log into Roblox. I see games that are scary, and some clean and fun for kids. I play all these games no matter the role, but it seems impossible that the age ratings around the world are appropriate for Roblox.

There are:

- Basic Games
- Easy and get-used-to games
- Kids'
- Scary and horrifying games

And there are, last of all, roleplaying games. I am confused of the age ratings people give. Therefore, what is the most official age rating for Roblox?

Comment: As ESRB always states: **Online Interactions Not Rated by the ESRB**.  The ESRB aside, its generally not possible to put a definitive rating on online interactions, which is a major component of Roblox and nearly all games now a days.

Comment: While the ESRB doesn't have a detailed breakdown of why they marked it E10+, PEGI does include some reasoning for their rating, which can be accessed using the link below and clicking the blue "More Info" button.  Other rating organizations may offer more detailed breakdowns, but there are countless resources online to chose from.  For example [this site](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/website-reviews/roblox) suggests 13+ with detailed reasons.  Ultimately, due to the online aspect and the creative nature of the game, it's really a question of what a parent/guardian is comfortable with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Officially, Roblox is available on multiple devices, each with it's own age rating.  There's also a lot of [gaming content rating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_content_rating_system#Comparison_table) with various resources to look up details on specific games:

- [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roblox.client&hl=en): Everyone 10+
- [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/roblox/id431946152): 12+
- ESRB (for [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/roblox/9nblgggzm6wm?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)/[Xbox](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/roblox/bq1tn1t79v9k?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)): Everyone 10+
- [PEGI](https://pegi.info/search-pegi?q=roblox&op=Search&age%5B%5D=&descriptor%5B%5D=&publisher=&platform%5B%5D=&release_year%5B%5D=&page=1&form_build_id=form-IeFY1YuTNgDOEPFSWQCkaRDFrWRQLKLAcx9lRAe_r1A&form_id=pegi_search_form): Ages 7+
- [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NUF4YOA): Guidance Suggested*

They also have a section on their website for parents [here](https://corp.roblox.com/parents/), which talks about the various systems in place to protect children.

That said, Roblox is a game focused on user-generated content, so it has the same problems that any game with online features runs into.

First, it's impossible to have this be a perfect system, so it's always possible that something inappropriate either slips through the cracks or has yet to be flagged and removed.

Additionally, Roblox has little to no control over related content posted elsewhere.  It's possible for there to be inappropriate Roblox content posted on other websites that a child might stumble upon from searching the web for Roblox media.

**Amazon defines this as "Based on information provided by the developer, the content of this application has material that is appropriate for most users. The app may include account creation, location detection, user generated content, advertisements, infrequent or mild references to violence, profanity, or crude themes, or other content not suitable for all ages."*